# wso2 Identity Server 5.9.0 setup overwriting carbon.xml

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 Identity Server 5.9.0 form rpm. 
Fedora 30 linux installation.
CARBON_HOME = /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.9.0/ 
I have all my development team via VPN, so I used /etc/hosts and setup siServer as 10.xxx.xxx.6 
I set up that ip at:

```
<HostName>siserver</HostName>
<MgtHostName>siserver</MgtHostName>
```

inside carbon.xml

But when I start it gets overwritten. I suspect some security policy.

LOG says:

> TID: [2019-12-16 12:18:32,320]  WARN
>   {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in
>   :repository/conf/carbon.xml {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} TID:
>   [2019-12-16 12:18:32,322]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
>   - Overriding files in configuration directory /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.9.0 {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}
>   TID: [2019-12-16 12:18:32,928]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Writing Metadata Entries...
>   {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser}

How do I avoid for my configuration to get overwritten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IS 5.9.0 introduced a new config model. According to the new config model, there is a centralized configuration file (deployment.toml) where users add the configurations, then those configurations will be added to the respective .xml files.

So if you want to do some changes in the carbon.xml file, you have to add the relevant configs in deployment.toml file according to the new config model. With the new config model, all the changes made by you in the xml config files will be overridden by the toml configs during the server startup.

Please refer to this document to know about new configuration model
https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2019/10/simplifying-configuration-with-WSO2-identity-server

You can change the host name in the deployment.toml file. Add the following config in deployment.toml file.

```
[server]  
hostname = "siserver"
```

If you already have these keys in deployment.toml file, change the value hostname as 'siserver' and restart the server.

Please refer to this documentation for further details about changing hostname in IS 5.9.0. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-the-hostname/

Comment: I needed to change the default port number so I used: offset = "2" after [server]